# Import data from mysql to specific database table in hive using sqoop is failed

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop, hadoop2

```
installed UBUNTU 14.04
installed HADOOP 2.7.1 version
installed SQOOP 1.4.6 version
installed XAMPP 7.0.1 version (for mysql)
installed HIVE 1.2.1

Trying to import data to HIVE by using below SQOOP command.

SQOOP Command example
```

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/world \
    --username root \
    --table CountryLanguage \
    --hive-import \
    --hive-table world.countrylanguage -m 1

```
Error Message
    database does not exists: world

Question
  1. is there anything wrong in the above command, please correct me?
```

Comment: Its seems the command is correct, but the connection to the mysql database is having some problem. You can try sqoop eval or sqoop list table command to verify the connection to the database.

Comment: thanks for your feedback Abhi. i tried to list the tables from "world" database in mysql using sqoop. its listing all the tables in "world" database. is there anything missing?

Comment: And i tired sqoop eval command also. i can able to get result from the tables.

Comment: --hive-table world.countrylanguage , Do you have a world database in Hive

Comment: yes i have "default" and "world" database in HIVE

Comment: i have changed to  "world.countrylanguage" to countrylanguage. sqoop saying import success to "default.countrylanguage" table. i can able to see data in HDFS. but i cant able to see the default.countrylanguage table in HIVE. Any guess?

Comment: i have created hive-site.xml file by copying hive-default.xml.template to hive-site.xml and changed ${system:java.io.tmpdir}/${system:user.name} by /tmp/hive. i tried with --hive-table countrylanguage in the command. its import to default.countrylanguage successfully. but i cant able to see the tables in HIVE even in "default" database also. experts please help me on this issue. i am stucking here.

Comment: This can be happening due to insufficient permissions on HDFS directory where default db is pointing to